# how to view details of a product in wordpress single.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to view the details of a product in single.php.

The product is inserted in a newly added table "products" in the WordPress database and it has no `post_type` or `post_id`.

Comment: Have you created the 'products' table or it is the 'prodcuts' table created by Woocommerce?

Comment: Please be more precise about what you want. Some code examples are welcome too if you have any. :)

Comment: @Jenis im not using woocommerce and its created by me.

Comment: @ lechariotdor, i don't have any code examples to show. Actually i need to view a product from its table in a single page like a post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are not saving your product as a custom post so you will not get the **post id** and correspondingly not able to fetch data using WordPress default funtions.

Then you need to write custom sql queries to get data on single.php for your products. You can create your custom functions on functions.php that will fetch the products data and then use that functions where required.

For example :

In `functions.php` you can create function as like :

```
function get_products(){
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM products ', OBJECT );
return $results;

}
```

In `single.php` you can get all these products as :

```
$products = get_products();
```

then you need to loop through this `$products` object array.

> the above mentioned example is for listing of all products.

Hope it will show you some light in the dark :)

Comment: Tnx for ur answer @ Jenis, can you please show me an example code for that.

Comment: its working for this link http://localhost/wordpress/hello-world/ which is a post. But its not working for http://localhost/wordpress/productname/ which is a product link. why it is so?

Comment: Because `single.php` can only be used for a `post` but as you said your `product` is not saved as a `post`. You may then need to create a custom template for it.

Comment: @ Jenis Thanks. It's true you show me some light in the dark :). I managed it with url rewriting rules and now its working fine. Thanks again.